# Let $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt {z}+\ln(4-x^2-y^2-z^2)$. Determine and describe the domain of $f$.

Tags: calculus

By the $f$ form, the constraints on $x,y$ y $z$ are:
\begin{align*}
     x\geq0, y\geq0, z\geq0, 4-x^2-y^2-z^2> 0.
\end{align*}
So the domain of $f$ is $D_f = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}^3: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <4 \}$, which is a $1/8$ of the interior of the sphere centered at the origin, which is in the first octant of $\mathbb{R}^3 $.

I think this is the correct solution, I await your comments. If anyone has a different solution or correction of my work I will be grateful.

Comment: Is it $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt {z}+\ln(4-x^2-y^2-z^\color{red}4\color{black})$ as in the title or $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt {z}+\ln(4-x^2-y^2-z^\color{red}2\color{black})$ as in the constraints?

Comment: "is a 1/8 of the interior of the sphere". Of *which* sphere (i.e. what is it's radius)? But yes, I think you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is right. You can just add a little more information, saying that the sphere (or rather ball) is centered at the origin **and of radius $\textbf{2}$** and you'll be good to go.